# Can't send ngfor index from HTML to child component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I tried to let my child component to read parents HTML's ngfor value to display the child page. But the child component seems didn't get the index number from the parent page.

This is my Parents: app.component.html:

```
     <ul *ngFor="let item of formDoc.components | keyvalue: valueAscOrder; let i = index ">
            <li *ngIf="item.value['type'] == 'columns'">
                <mat-card [style.backgroundColor]="'white'" [style.border]="lightgrey" [style.width]="'50%'">
                    {{item.value["label"]}}

                    <app-columns [indexnumber]="i"></app-columns>

                </mat-card>

            </li>
      </ul>
```

And this is the child: Columns.component.ts

```
import { FormBuilderComponent } from 'angular-formio';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
//import { ColumnComponent } from 'src/column/Column.component';
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component'

@Injectable()

@Component({
  selector: 'app-columns',
  templateUrl: './Columns.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Columns.component.scss'],
})

export class ColumnsComponent {
    @Input() columnsData: object[]; 
    public saveData: object[];
    @Input() public indexnumber: string; 

    constructor(public appComponent: AppComponent){ 
        if (this.indexnumber) {
            this.columnsData = appComponent.Temp2[this.indexnumber]["component"];
        }
    }
}
```

The value of indexnumber is always undefined. I'm wondering how to make index number in Columns.component.ts get the ngfor 'i' value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist of all, the index of an array is a number, not a string. So

```
@Input() public indexnumber: string;
```

should be

```
@Input() public indexnumber: number;
```

Second: in order for angular to be able to set the indexnumber of your component, your component needs to exist. So it must have been constructed *before*. So, at the time the constructor is invoked, the input can't possibly have been set yet. So trying to access the value of an input in the constructor can't possibly give you the value passed by the parent.

Use ngOnInit or ngOnChanges. That's the methods that are called when the inputs are set for the first time/changed.

Comment: ngOnInit(){
        this.columnsData = this.appComponent.Temp2[this.indexnumber]["component"];
    }